# Preg Please for json Multi Dimension string

Tags: php, json

i have string like this :

```
<?php
echo $str_is;
?>
```

Result :

```
[["id_is","'bG1saW50YXMgbWFoYWthbTMyMTI'"],["date_is","'2015-2-25'"]]
```

I need to get array like this :

```
$thearray["id_is"]="'bG1saW50YXMgbWFoYWthbTMyMTI'"
$thearray["date_is"]="'2015-2-25'"
```

i was tried using (im newbie using code preg_match) :

```
$thearray = preg_match('/[(\w+)/],([(\w+)/]/', $str_is, $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be one way to do it:

```
$str_is = <<< EOS
[["id_is","'bG1saW50YXMgbWFoYWthbTMyMTI'"],["date_is","'2015-2-25'"]]
EOS;

// Convert the JSON string to an array
$array = json_decode($str_is, true);

// Loop the array adding to $thearray
foreach ($array as $pair) {
   // First element = key (e.g. "id_is")
   // Second element = value (e.g. "'bG1saW50YXMgbWFoYWthbTMyMTI'")
    $thearray[$pair[0]] = $pair[1];
}

echo $thearray['id_is'], PHP_EOL;
echo $thearray['date_is'], PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
'bG1saW50YXMgbWFoYWthbTMyMTI'
'2015-2-25'
```